# C++: invalid conversion from char to char*?

Tags: c++

I receive this error:

> array.cpp: In function ‘void strcat2(char*, const char*)’:
>   array.cpp:74: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’
>   array.cpp:74: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void strcpy2(char*, const char*)’
>   array.cpp:74: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’
>   array.cpp:74: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void strcpy2(char*, const char*)’

When trying to run this code:

```
//Concatenates two arrays of characters using pointers
void strcat2(char* t, const char* s)
{
        unsigned int i;

        for (i = 0; *t; i++);
        strcpy2(*(t + i), *s);
}
```

Here is the strcpy2 function it calls:

```
//Copies the information from one array of characters to another using pointers
void strcpy2(char* t, const char* s)
{
        for ( ; *t++ = *s++;);
}
```

It says invalid conversion from char to char*, but where am I trying to convert from char to char*?  It seems to me that everything in the code is char*.  What am I missing?

I've looked over this code many times and can't seem to find what is wrong.  I'm relatively new to pointers, go easy!  Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: If you're truly using C++, might I suggest `std::string`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that this is for an assignment.

Comment: I figured, as only in academia would they ask you to use `char*` for strings in C++ ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
*(t + i)
```

`t` is of type `char *`.

so `t + i` means `char * + i` which means "add the value of i to the pointer to make a new pointer". `*(t + i)` then dereferences that new pointer, the type of that dereferenced expression will be `char`. So yes, the compiler is correct. You're trying to pass a `char` into a function that expects a `pointer-to-char`.

You simply want

```
strcpy2(t + i, s);
```

note: You were also dereferencing `s`, which would cause the same compile error.

Comment: Thank you!  You explained it very well.  Also,  the `;` after the for isn't a bug, because the for doesn't actually do anything but increment i while *t is true (the strcpy2 isn't under the for loop).

Comment: @Pod  the ; after the for is not a bug.

Comment: Correct -- I misread it. I usually stick a comment similar to /* deliberate */ after such a thing. My eyes are so used to the normal idiomatic for loops that I didn't even look at what the for loop is doing :)

Answer (score 1):

The expression `*(t + i)` in `strcpy2(*(t + i), *s);` is a char type because the `*` dereferences the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Change these statements

```
for (i = 0; *t; i++);

strcpy2(*(t + i), *s);
```

to

```
for (i = 0; *(t + i ); i++);
strcpy2( t + i, s);
```

Also it would be better to declare the functions as having return type `char *`. For example

```
char * strcat2(char* t, const char* s);
```